# Typescript Mixins not working as intended in the compiler

Tags: typescript, mongoose, declaration, mongoose-schema, mixins

So I have a class and interface declared with the same name.

```
declare module "mongoose"
{
  class Schema<T = any>
  {
    constructor(definition?: SchemaDefinition);
  }
  interface Schema<T = any>
  {
    new(definition?: TypedSchemaDefinition<T>): Schema<T>;
  }
}
```

Let assume that `TypedSchemaDefinition` just converts the type parameter props into their run-time counterpart. I'm not going to include all the code that does achieves this functionality for simplicity purpose unless its required.

Example props: compile type => runtime type & string => String & number => Number etc...

This should not throw an error.

```
interface ShippingCompileType {
 days: number,
 price: number,
}
const ShippingRuntimeType: TypedSchemaDefinition<ShippingCompileType> = {
  days: Number,
  price: Number,
}
const ShippingSchema = new Schema(ShippingRuntimeType);

Error: TypedSchemaDefinition<ShippingCompileType> is not assignable to SchemaDefinition
```

I don't know if this is a bug or an intended feature, because mixins and declaration merging should merge the two constructor type and allow `ShippingRuntimeType` as a valid parameter of the function. If this is a bug, then is there a work around??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete .vs file and add the file into the type root in order to fix the typescript modules IntelliSense.